# How checksum line works in a manifest.json file used in shiny app?

Tags: r, json, shiny

You can see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/connect-api-deploy-shiny/blob/master/manifest.json) a `manifest.json` file used to connect shiny app with API. I would like someone to explain to me the  `"checksum": "ed1521f080df2ef2e83a7d1c5fb944c1"`. What does that do ? I have seen that I can create reports with this for example like:

```
 "AQ_Report_Clean_Spanish.pdf": {
      "checksum": "ed1521f080df2ef2e83a7d1c5fb944c1"
    },
```

but what exactly does this id-like line does? If for example I want to create another report I have to change that "id" as well or just the report name like:

```
"AQ_Report_Clean.pdf": {
          "checksum": "ed1521f080df2ef2e83a7d1c5fb944c1"
        },
```

Comment: The parent repo mentions the function `rsconnect::writeManifest`. You can see additional usage here: https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/user/git-backed/#creating-a-manifest-file-from-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general answer not r & shiny specific:

It seems to be the checksum of the file mentioned above. You could verify by creating a md5 checksum (or some others) for the file here https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/md5_checksum.html.

The checksum helps to verify if the file could be downloaded/transferred as expected.

Comment: wow impressive I added the 2 pdfs and they had different checksum so I will need to change in the manifest.json script file as well.very helpful